# InstagramAPI Error 400 Checkpoint Challenge Required

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram-api

I'm using the InstagramAPI for the first time and I'm getting the following response when I try to login:

```
Request return 400 error!
{'message': 'challenge_required', 'challenge': {'url': 'https://i.instagram.com/challenge/1721369303/mv7oIW3Hqh/', 'api_path': '/challenge/1721369303/mv7oIW3Hqh/', 'hide_webview_header': True, 'lock': True, 'logout': False, 'native_flow': True}, 'status': 'fail', 'error_type': 'checkpoint_challenge_required'}
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
class InstaBot:

    def __init__(self):
        self.api = InstagramAPI("my_username", "my_password")




bot = InstaBot()
```

I've seen where there have been issues with instagram api's before, and was curious if this api is outdated or if there is something I'm not doing

Answer (score 0):

Challenge means that IG suspects your new login to be a login from unusual device/place and tries to verify if it real account owner or not. You can try solving this challenge or use same device-id (android-xxx) and location. Or you can pass existing session cookies.